# How to use mixed text and date field in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, view

Is there anyway I can use a view/inline table function to query a table using a date range in the where clause on a field which contains both text and dates.

The date field datatype is nvarchar and contains text and text dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy.`

I have tried using a CTE/Subquery using the `ISDATE` function to exclude non-date values, using a `DATEFORMAT` setting of dmy. This works sometimes but most of the time this error occurs.

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I cannot change the design of the table or system. I am already using a multi-statement table function to achieve this but would like to know if this is possible using inline.

This is using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Connect item describes your problem:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

You have to always wrap the date (/text mix) column with a CASE expression and NULL-ify the non-dates before carrying them forward from the CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have solved a similar problem. Try this solution if it is right for you -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (dt VARCHAR(12))

INSERT INTO @temp (dt)
VALUES 
  ('12/12/2012')
, ('13/12/2012')
, ('14/12/2012')
, ('string')
, ('14/05/2013')
, ('test/2013')

DECLARE @t TABLE (dt DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT dt = CONVERT(DATETIME, t.dt, 104)
FROM @temp t
WHERE t.dt LIKE '__/__/____' -- '[1-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-2]/____'

SELECT * 
FROM @t 
WHERE dt BETWEEN '20121212' AND '20121213'
```

Comment: Whilst this may work I was looking for a solution using a view or inline table function. This would create a multi statement function which I already have. Thanks.